# MySQL - Which DML sentences EXACTLY acquire an exclusive lock?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, locking, dml

Of the DML statements, **only the UPDATE and DELETE** acquire an exclusive lock?

Comment: Not only. `REPLACE`, `INSERT .. ODKU`, `LOAD DATA REPLACE` and `LOAD XML REPLACE` should acquire an exclusive lock too, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Summary of Locks Obtained by DML Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502)!

Comment: hi @Terence_TheDeveloper "Row Locks (TX) A row lock, also called a TX lock, is a lock on a single row of a table. A transaction acquires a row lock for each row modified by one of the following statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, and SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. The row lock exists until the transaction commits or rolls back." - is this the specific part of my question, isn't it? (I'm confused by the term Row Locks that's why I'm asking you).

Comment: I believe this is the specific part [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502:~:text=Summary%20of%20Locks%20Obtained%20by%20DML%20Statements)

Comment: MySQL <> OracleDB.

Comment: Correct @Akina, do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: @Daniel No, I have interested in this never.